# Will ES6 RegExps support the Iterator protocol?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, iterator-protocol

I'm unable to find an answer in [the spec](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-regexp-constructor) or [list of proposals](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proposals) as to whether RegExps in ES6 will provide the necessary methods to support the [Iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/The_Iterator_protocol) for matched groups. There are a number of symbol methods, but I'm not familiar enough with the semantics of the various symbols to tell if they will provide this.

I would imagine something like:

```
var rex = /((\w+)\s?)*/;
var res = rex.exec("test string");

console.log(res);

for (let match of res) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

This seems to work in 6to5's REPL, logging the expected `"test string"`, `"string"`, `"string"`.

Is this specifically defined in the ES6 spec, and if not, what properties of the regex result allow it to work? Or is it just an artifact of 6to5 not being exactly ES6?

Comment: for (match in res)  works now, so there's probably no special considerations, other than the _of_ operator

Comment: This has nothing to do with changes in `RegExp` API. Rather, what you are looping through is an array containing the main match and the captured text of **a single match**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`res` is just an `Array` of matches. You can check it using one of the next variants:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(res) === '[object Array]'
res instanceof Array;
Array.isArray(res);
res.constructor === Array;
```

And arrays in ES6 supports iterator interface. See [here](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:iterators), or in MDN: [Array.prototype[@@iterator]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/@@iterator)

What about `input` and `index` properties - they just added to the `res` array by `exec` method. For example you can check v8 source code:

- [RexExpExec method](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/regexp.js#L158) JS
- [RegExpImpl::Exec](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/jsregexp.cc#L226) C++
- [SetLastMatchedInfo](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/jsregexp.cc#L663) (last matched info is our `res` object)

Comment: is _res_ an Array? i also see an index property on there, not defined by Array.prototype. If it's an Array with non-expando object properties, that contradicts best practices. match() prodeces an Array, but does exec() as well?

Comment: @dandavis I updated the answer. `index` and `input` properties is just added to `res` array by `exec` method.

Comment: nice dig! I guess all those commentators who bark about adding non-numeric keys onto Arrays need to give it a rest; it's not a sin if god does it...

Comment: @dandavis: You still shouldn't use arrays to store arbitrary data in arbitrary keys. You can always put specific properties on them, though.

Comment: This is a good (and seemingly correct) answer as is, but would be fantastic with the `index`/`input` notes edited in. ;)

Comment: @ssube Year, I did it.